# How to transfer unlocked sol from account through CLI Wallet

Tags: solana-cli

I received some locked sol on a CLI wallet. The sol has unlocked recently and I was trying to transfer the sol to another wallet.

I am using this command:

```
solana transfer --keypair ~/keypair.json --from [locked sol account] [target address] 5
```

However when I run the command I receive the following:

```
Error: Dynamic program error: missing signature for supplied pubkey: [locked sol account]
```

The keypair I am using is the withdrawer authority of the account. I guess I am a little confused on how the withdrawer authority should be used? Does it sign the transaction? Should I be using the `--signer` instead?

**UPDATE**

After going through the documentation this was a misunderstanding on how locked sol in stake accounts work.. In case anyone else runs into this to withdraw from the staked account running the following:

```
solana withdraw-stake [locked sol account] [target account] [amount]
```